# Is there any downloadable Photoshop CS5 Lens Profile for iPhone (3GS)?

Tags: lens, iphone

Either user- or Adobe-created, is there any downloadable lens profile for iPhone (3GS) cameras for Photoshop, for use with Lens Correction?

Comment: What do you mean, that lens is flawless! Kidding... :)

Comment: dpollitt: hilarious. :D Yeah, top notch quality stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I would try out the Adobe Lens Profile Creator available at [Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/). It can help you correct geometric distortion, lateral chromatic aberration and vignette issues. It does take a bit of work for you to create one, but it isn't terribly hard. Once you get it setup, it is easy sailing from then on out.

I was not able to find a prebuilt iPhone 3GS profile, so this is the next best thing.

Comment: Cool.  We're (SmugMug iOS team) going to make some for all the devices and the Schneider lenses too, thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: dpollitt: thanks for your reply. I'm undecided whether to mark it as the accepted answer, as I knew about the Adobe Lens Profile Creator, but (being lazy) was looking for someone else having created such profiles with it. :) If you or someone else find any readymade iPhone profiles out there, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: @hced - Totally understandable. I wouldn't create one either, as I am also lazy :) I'm sure someone will make one and update here eventually, then you will have an accepted answer!